# How do I create a keyboard listener in python that will return the character of the pressed key?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard

For instance, when the "f" key is pressed, the function would return the character "f", such that I could then run ord(key) and get the ascii value of the key pressed. I am attempting to make a program that emulates the Enigma cypher machine and want inputs to be given straight from the keyboard while the window is in focus, and the cypher outputs are printed onto the console. (on a separate but related note I am having trouble remembering how to get the print() function to omit the newline character after its output). It looks to me like the pynput Keyboard module is the tool for this, but I'm not quite clear on how to use it.
This is my complete code so far. the "on_press", and "on_release" functions, as well as everything after the "with Listener(..." are just taken from the internet (https://pythonhosted.org/pynput/keyboard.html) and, to be honest, I don't know what they do or how to use them.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

wheels = {fst:[19,-1 , 4 , -2, 11,-3 , 12,-4 , 8 ,-5 , 10,-6 , 9 , 0 , 11,-8 , 8 ,-9 , 5 ,-10, 2 ,-10,-5 ,-13,-10,-13],
          med:[2 , 6 , 10, 5 , 0 , 15, 12,-6 , 13, 2 ,-10, 11,-3 ,-7 , 0 , 8 ,-13,-1 ,-5 ,-9 ,-15, 4 ,-3 ,-8 ,-7 ,-1 ],
          slo:[16, 17, 19, 16,-3 ,-2 , 4 , 17, 6 , 0 ,-8 ,-3 , 13,-9 ,-7 ,-10,-16,-6 ,-5 ,-4 , 3 ,-4 ,-2 ,-1 ,-18,-13],
          rfl:[8 , 22, 18, 4 , 1 ,-1 , 19,-4 ,-8 , 5 , 2 , 8 ,-2 , 3 ,-5 , 7 ,-3 , 1 ,-1 ,-8 ,-18, 3 ,-7 ,-22,-3 ,-19]}
dials = [0, 0, 0, 0]

def incr():
  dials[0] = (dials[0] + 1) % 26
  if(dials[0]==0):
    dials[1] = (dials[1] + 1) % 26
  if(dials[1]==0):
    dials[2] = (dials[2] + 1) % 26

def shift(char,level):
  return(chr(ord(char) - 97 + wheels[level][(ord(char) - 97 + dials[level]) % 26]))
  
def on_press(key):
  print('{0} pressed'.format(key))

def on_release(key):
  print('{0} release'.format(key))
  if key == Key.esc:
    return False

def route(char):
  #process the character through each level of scrambling
  incr()

with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
  listener.join()
```

Comment: I'm not too sure how to solve your main problem but as for the new line print issue, you can omit new lines by using the end parameter of the print function.
eg. print('Hello world', end='')
Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print

Comment: ah, thank you for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general spirit of Listeners is that they "listen" to your keyboard for any keys that you may type.

In your code above (and taken from the website), the `on_press` function is called when you press down on a certain key, distinct from releasing a key. This function is useful because we can attempt to store the information (the key) that was pressed for later use (for your Enigma cypher machine).

The `on_release` function can be thought as the function which helps determine if the Listener should stop listening to your keyboard. If the `on_release` function returns False, the listener ends.

For the purpose of your project, I wrote some janky modification to your code above that should help you move on past listening to the keyboard.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

wheels = {'fst':[19,-1 , 4 , -2, 11,-3 , 12,-4 , 8 ,-5 , 10,-6 , 9 , 0 , 11,-8 , 8 ,-9 , 5 ,-10, 2 ,-10,-5 ,-13,-10,-13],
          'med':[2 , 6 , 10, 5 , 0 , 15, 12,-6 , 13, 2 ,-10, 11,-3 ,-7 , 0 , 8 ,-13,-1 ,-5 ,-9 ,-15, 4 ,-3 ,-8 ,-7 ,-1 ],
          'slo':[16, 17, 19, 16,-3 ,-2 , 4 , 17, 6 , 0 ,-8 ,-3 , 13,-9 ,-7 ,-10,-16,-6 ,-5 ,-4 , 3 ,-4 ,-2 ,-1 ,-18,-13],
          'rfl':[8 , 22, 18, 4 , 1 ,-1 , 19,-4 ,-8 , 5 , 2 , 8 ,-2 , 3 ,-5 , 7 ,-3 , 1 ,-1 ,-8 ,-18, 3 ,-7 ,-22,-3 ,-19]}
dials = [0, 0, 0, 0]

def incr():
  dials[0] = (dials[0] + 1) % 26
  if(dials[0]==0):
    dials[1] = (dials[1] + 1) % 26
  if(dials[1]==0):
    dials[2] = (dials[2] + 1) % 26

def shift(char,level):
  return(chr(ord(char) - 97 + wheels[level][(ord(char) - 97 + dials[level]) % 26]))

def on_press(key):
  # Use global variable input in order to keep track of current word.
  global userInput
  try:
    userInput += key.char
  except AttributeError:
    #print('special key {0} pressed'.format(key))
    if key == Key.space: 
      userInput += ' '

def on_release(key):
  if key == Key.enter:
    return False
  elif key == Key.esc: 
    return False

def route(char):
  #process the character through each level of scrambling
  incr()


# esc to escape listener.
userInput = ""
with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
  listener.join()
print('userInput', userInput)
```

From this point on, you would have to incorporate the userInput into your the Enigma cypher aspect of your machine. I should mention that I made minor modifications to your code. For instance, the Listener should be able to understand spaces.

If you have any follow up questions, please let me know.

Comment: hmm... okay, so is the try/except because space is treated as 'space' and not ' '?

Comment: also, I don't think I want it  as one concatenated variable. the reason I wanted to use a listener instead of an input function is so that I can process the keys as they are pressed and then print them out (without the trailing newline) as they are being typed. would I do this by simply adding on to the "on_press" definition, and telling it to printout each processed letter instead of adding them to the variable?

Comment: If you wanted to process the characters as they are being pressed then yes, you would make that modification in `on_press`